# Is it safe to downgrade X?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, downgrade

I have an old graphics-card which needs the nvidia-96 drivers. But the drivers need xorg-video-abi-10 to be installed, and my version of Ubuntu (Precise) has (i think) an newer version, because that package is not available in the repos.

I need the graphics drivers for OpenGL programs like Google Earth, Blender, etc.

Is it safe to downgrade X or will it break other programs (like Unity 2D)? And if yes, where do I get the package from?

Comment: Actualy, I think I _could_ try the downgrade anyway—even if it doesn't work I could always upgrade again. But where do I get the package from?

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically you can try the downgrade. Use `synaptic` to do this.

Comment: The package (`xorg-video-abi-10`) isn't available in the repository, so I can't add it using Synaptic. Is there a PPA or something I can get the package from? I tried googling but couldn't find anything...